# Get Magento permalink URL for cart?

Tags: cart, url

I used to use Shopify and the permalink to fill a cart was something like:
http://domainname.myshopify.com/cart/370374:1,377854:1,37067790:1

Is there a similar way to do this with Magento? So far I've tried:

https://domainname.com/checkout/cart/add?product=99750&qty=1

But they don't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

in this https://domainname.com/checkout/cart/add?product=99750&qty=1
you are missing form_key parameter

It will look likes,
https://domainname.com/checkout/cart/add?product=99750&qty=1&form_key=crtH4Ol3DYNeSFr5

form_key is dynamically generated key, you can get it as below and pass it to url

```
$form_key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```

Pass $form_key value while building url

```
$url = "https://domainname.com/checkout/cart/add?product=99750&qty=1&form_key=".$form_key;
```

Use above $url in your action call

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Is there a way to find the form key without being logged into the site, as the site is not mine?